# Calculate dataframe similar rows

Tags: r, matrix

I am new to R.
I have a data frame (New1) contains 400 row and 5 column.
This is an example:

```
A   B   C   D   E
0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   1
0   0   0   0   2
0   0   0   1   0
0   0   0   1   1
0   0   0   1   2
0   0   0   2   0
0   0   0   2   1
```

I want to add a new column where number of same events occures.
For example number of events of (A=0, B=0, C=0, D=0, E=0) in this table 0.
then number of events (A=0, B=0, C=0, D=0, E=1) in this table 1.
and so on.

Is that doable in R.

Comment: Not obvious to understand what you want .. May you give some sample data, so that people can try to do what your are trying to do ?

Comment: How is your question related to the title of the question? Adding a column to an existing dataframe is not the same thing as converting a matrix to a dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
#sample Mat

Mat <-structure(c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
                1L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L), .Dim = c(8L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(
                  NULL, NULL))

library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = F)

Mat
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#> [1,]    0    0    0    0    0
#> [2,]    0    0    0    0    1
#> [3,]    0    0    0    0    2
#> [4,]    0    0    0    1    0
#> [5,]    0    0    0    1    1
#> [6,]    0    0    0    1    2
#> [7,]    0    0    0    2    0
#> [8,]    0    0    0    2    1

Mat %>% as.data.frame() %>% setNames(LETTERS[1:ncol(.)]) %>%
  mutate(total = rowSums(cur_data()))
#>   A B C D E total
#> 1 0 0 0 0 0     0
#> 2 0 0 0 0 1     1
#> 3 0 0 0 0 2     2
#> 4 0 0 0 1 0     1
#> 5 0 0 0 1 1     2
#> 6 0 0 0 1 2     3
#> 7 0 0 0 2 0     2
#> 8 0 0 0 2 1     3
```

---

As requested in comments, for saving csv use write.csv

```
Mat %>% as.data.frame() %>% setNames(LETTERS[1:ncol(.)]) %>%
  mutate(total = rowSums(cur_data())) %>%
  write.csv('path\\filename.csv')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your big help.
Is it possible to extract these result as a table including total?

Comment: I am sorry for my frequent question. Is it suppose to be like this
m %>% as.data.frame() %>% setNames(LETTERS[1:ncol(.)]) %>%
mutate(total = rowSums(cur_data())
write.csv())

Comment: again I am sorry for continuous disturbing. 
I keep facing this issue (even though I changed dimension to actual size which is 900 as follow Dim = c(900L, 5L))
The error is: Error in attributes(.Data) <- c(attributes(.Data), attrib) : dims [product 4500] do not match the length of object [40]

Comment: I did that because actual dataset contains 900 rows. Each time I run this code it generate an 8 column csv even after replacing m with data name

Comment: so replace `Mat` with that dataname, why changing sample data dput?  edited my answer.  Seems that you are extremely new to R

Comment: Thanks a lot for your patience. Yes I mentioned that I am new to R in my question

Comment: Do you have a dataframe or matrix?  What is its name?

Comment: It is 'NewPrice'.
I tired again following your instruction but same issue, it generate only 8 rows. I attached an Image.

Comment: it is dataframe or matrix?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234562/discussion-between-ohoud-0-and-anilgoyal).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234571/discussion-between-anilgoyal-and-ohoud-0).